# How to display an int in WinApi (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, int, display

I'm struggling with displaying of an int in  WinApi in C++. I have a drawing function

```
void MyOnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Pen pen(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
    Pen pen2(Color(255, 25*col, 0, 255));

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        graphics.DrawLine(&pen2, data[i - 1].X, data[i - 1].Y, data[i].X, data[i].Y);


    graphics.DrawRectangle(&pen, 50 + value, 400, 10, 20);
}
```

And i would like to display an integer (for example value) every time the method is called (the value of value keeps changeing so it it would be updating every time I call the method).

I heard something about Graphics.DrawString but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: This looks like a C# question rather than a C++/Winapi question.

Comment: @Sean No, it looks like a C++/GDI+ question

Comment: It's time to learn about sprintf and other related standard functions.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: If you don't know about `sprintf` and friends in C++, it's best to **not** learn about them. C++ has safer alternatives ([stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) or [to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `int` to string (a sequence of characters), e.g. using [`std::to_wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring). Draw the string. API functions like [`DrawString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) help tremendously with the latter.